# How to integrate/differentiate parameters in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE, which I would be fine about solving, were it not for the parameter:
$$(\omega^2+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$
I'm given that $\omega>0$ is a parameter. Separating the variables gives:

$$\int\frac{1}{y}dy=\int\frac{1}{\omega^2+x^2}dx$$

Essentially, my question is: *can I just treat $\omega$ as a constant, so yielding the integral on RHS to be $\frac{1}{\omega}\arctan\frac{x}{\omega}$?*

(If this is wrong, and I'm to treat $\omega$  as a variable, how do I solve this DE?)
Thanks.

Comment: "can I just treat $\omega$ as a constant" -- that's what being a parameter means, so yes.  (It might depend on the physical problem -- different springs have different parameters for Hooke's law -- but once you're working with a particular spring it's a constant.)